# Changing the background color of buttons with SQL Server datatable, reference by button name

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, for-loop

I am currently using vb.net express 2013 in windows form applications. I have created a list of "cell locations" via a SQL query. I have 84 button that are design named as `cmdM01`, `cmdM02`, ...., `cmd84`. I am running a loop to turn all the buttons green and the I want to turn the buttons that macth the sql query to red. I have it all except one line I believe. Can someone help me with the control line? I need any button whose name matches the SQL query return to turn red.

```
        Dim ctr As Control
    Try
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT LocID from Production.dbo.tblFabWipID Left Join Production.dbo.tblFabWiplog ON tblFabWipID.FabWipID = tblFabWipLog.fabwipid WHERE CheckedIN IS NOT NULL AND  CheckedOut is NULL", conn1)
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                sql.Fill(dt)
                For Each ctr In PanelButtons.Controls
                    If TypeOf ctr Is Button Then
                        ctr.BackColor = Color.Green
                        For Each row In dt.Rows
                            Me.Controls("cmd" & Button.BackColor.red)
                        Next
                  End If

                Next
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error loading button identification during load event, please contact ")
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
```

Comment: PS. each button is a cell location.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: 2 important questions: Is "LocId" the rest of the name of your control (ie, M01, M02, 84)? Second, do you expect your select to return multiple records or only 1?

Comment: One issue is that you are not populating your `DataTable`.  Add `sql.Fill(dt)` before your first `For Each` loop.

Comment: @Steve The LocID is the rest of the name, I set it up that way so I could use the name to select certain buttons. The selection should return multiple selections. The design name of my buttons are cmdM01, cmdM02, etc etc, The name in my sql datatable is just M01, M02, etc etc.

Comment: @Mark I will add the fill code in real quick. I just had this typed up and I realized I did not know how to use the button name.

Comment: Are you then looking for something like `Me.Controls("cmd" & row("LocID")).BackColor = Color.Red`?  You could also move that loop outside the other one.

Comment: @Mark I think that is exactly what im looking form, im getting an error saying object variable or With block variable not set. But I think a variation of that line of code is exactly what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PanelButtons.Controls` in both cases, and use the `LocID` from each `DataRow` to form the control name. The loops also don't need to be nested.

```vb
For Each ctr In PanelButtons.Controls
    If TypeOf ctr Is Button Then
        ctr.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
Next
For Each row In dt.Rows
    Dim btn = PanelButtons.Controls("cmd" & row("LocID"))
    If btn IsNot Nothing Then
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
Next
```